# Pure CSS Change Background Color of Fixed Navbar on Scroll?

Tags: html, css

I am just wondering if there is a pure CSS way to change the background color of a fixed navbar when scrolling past a certain vertical point?  I am wondering if this can be done in CSS based on the ID of another element, or a height?

I know of ways in JavaScript to achieve this but am wondering if the same thing can be achieved with pure CSS. Thank you for the assist!

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate this using gradient and `background-attachment:fixed`.

Here is an example:

```css
.fixed {
   height:100px;
   width:100%;
   position:fixed;
   color:#fff;
}


body {
  height:300vh;
  background:    
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 0 100px/100% 100% no-repeat fixed,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 300px, red 0) center/100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  this is a fixed navbar where the color will change after 300px of scroll
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution there.  Thanks for the help!